# "isc_attach_database failed" error FlameRobin for connect Firebird database

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5, flamerobin

I'm trying setup Firebird 2.5 with FlameRobin 0.9.3, installed on Windows 10 64bit. The .fdb files are on the same disk of the Firebird machine and the FlameRobin program.

[image: My DB Files located D: drive]

I'm trying to connect EMPLOYEE.FDB file with FlameRobin getting this error.

[image: FlameRobin error]

My settings for this database file below.

[image: My settings]

I never changed my sysdba password. Is it due to this error ODBC driver?

Edit: I've created a new database on ISQL to try. Username: SYSDBA Password: 31202333

[image: Successful create database]

But I am getting same error on FlameRobin.

[image: Same error]

Comment: Given FlameRobin doesn't use ODBC, this has not to do with any ODBC driver. The error usually means you're using the wrong password.

Comment: @mickmackusa Sorry, I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that your username does not exist (unlikely for SYSDBA), or the password is incorrect<sup>*</sup>. In Firebird, passwords are system wide, not per database. Check your password (default installations of Firebird on Windows use the password 'masterkey'). Otherwise try resetting the password using [gsec](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/gsec/firebird-gsec.html#gsec-amending).

The fact it might work with ISQL, is that you're using a local path, which may cause ISQL to use Firebird embedded mode, and in embedded mode on Windows, the password is ignored (on the assumption that if you have filesystem access to the database file, you are allowed to open database). I guess that, if instead of `'D:\sq\sample.fdb'`, you'd use `'localhost:D:\sq\sample.fdb'` in ISQL, you would get the same error as in FlameRobin.

*: In Firebird 3 and later it can also mean that the user does not exist for the authentication plugins tried, even though the user may exist for a different authentication plugin.

Comment: I get a "Cannot attach to services manager" error when I try to connect gsec.

Comment: Either stop Firebird and try again, or use the `-database localhost:<path-to>/security2.fdb` option (where `<path-to>` needs to be replaced with the actual path of the security2.fdb on your system).

Comment: I am getting:
Unable to complete network request to host "localhost".
Failed to establish a connection.
unable to open database

Comment: @zokanzi In which case? Exactly what did you do?

Comment: I stopped Firebird service and try your "gsec  -database localhost:C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\security2.fdb" command

Comment: @zokanzi Either you haven't started Firebird, and/or you need to use `-database 'localhost:C:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_2_5\security2.fdb'` (see https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/gsec-cmdline.html)

Comment: C:\Program Files\Firebird2.5\bin>gsec -database localhost:C:\Program Files\Firebird2.5\security2.fdb.
invalid parameter, no switch defined.
error in switch specifications.
use gsec -? to get help.
Cannot attach to services manager.
user name and password are required while attaching to the services manager
unable to open database. when i started service

Comment: Mark, while he is *saying* he is using FB 2.5, but his console screenshots says *FB 3.0*

Comment: Thanks @Arioch'The . I uninstall all versions of installed Firebird and reinstalled a clean installation. Now i connect a database now. I'm sorry to keep you busy especially Mark.